# Using GraphicalEffects in PySide6

Tags: qt, qml, pyside2, pyside6, qt6

I am using PySide6 and am trying to use the GraphicalEffects module.

As per documentation here:
https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtgraphicaleffects5-index.html

I am doing:

```
import Qt5Compat.QtGraphicalEffects
```

The error I am getting:

```
"Qt5Compat.QtGraphicalEffects" is not installed
```

How do I install this module? I have PySide6.2.2.1 installed on my Linux machine.

Comment: The Graphical Effects module is provided for backward compatibility with Qt5. Are you actually porting from Qt5, or are you trying to get a graphics effect (which uses shaders in Qt6)? Also, do you need it for QML or QWidgets?

Comment: I am rewriting my project from Qt5 to Qt6. I need it for QML and all I need to implement is LinearGradient and ColorOverlay.

Comment: It seems that you need to install the `qt6-5compat` package.

Comment: I can't find that package for Debian, only for Arch linux.

Comment: Same type of Issue on [Reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/QtFramework/comments/pskq58/import_qt5compatgraphicaleffects_qml_module_not/) too

Comment: opened an issue in qt issue tracker https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1957

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Its a [known issue](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1957) when installing from pypi. It will be fixed in pyside 6.4.

You can also [build from source](https://doc.qt.io/qtforpython-6/gettingstarted.html) and it will be added automatically if you installed it with Qt-online installer.

Comment: I can't edit and the "known issue" link is broken since it has an empty space in the formatting, so here: [known issue](https://bugreports.qt.io/browse/PYSIDE-1957)

Comment: I have PySide6 (plus Addons and Essentials pkgs) version 6.5.1.1, and still have: module "Qt5Compat.QtGraphicalEffects" is not installed. End up using QtQuick.Shapes.LinearGradient instead.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative would be to copy the module from the root directory and include it in the development environment.

Here is a more detailed description: [QT6.4 QML PYTHON module "Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects" is not installed](https://www.it-hinca.de/de/blog/blog-news/qt-6-4-qml-python-missing-liberary-module-qt5compat-graphical-effects-is-not-installed.html)

Works with Pyside6 or PyQt6.

Answer (score 0):

I was struggling when importing `Qt5Compat.GraphicalEffects` inside my `Qml`files and it always says in QtCreator, this error :

```
Qml Module not found ... Import paths :C:\Qt\6.6.1\mingw_64\qml
```

I have Pyside 6.6.1 and this is the solution that I did :
"I am using QtCreator and it generates a Python virtual environment inside QtCreator and I looked in installed packages here:

```
<your_project_name>\venv\Lib\site-packages\PySide6\qml
├── Qt
├── Qt3D
├── Qt5Compat
│   └── GraphicalEffects // found it !!
...
```

then simply what I did was copy this qml folder into :

```
C:\Qt\6.6.1\mingw_64\qml
```

where it would be imported , and it worked

ps: idk if that could generate some problems because Modifying the Qt install location directly could cause issues !!